# AngularJs directive access in new Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have an Angular v5 application running on the same page as an AngularJs v1.2.23 application. Is it possible to access & use a directive from the older AngularJs application in the new Angular without refactoring?

Comment: See also, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-Based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).